# Swing Repaint Bleeding

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying out a program with Java Swing that draws Random Lines on a `JPanel`. For this I have overridden the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the JPanel.

I'm also using a Thread to continuously repaint the component with a fixed delay between repaints.

The thread is being controlled by a `JButton` that can start and stop the painting of the component.

The whole panel is then embedded in a `JFrame` and shown on screen.

When I execute the code and Start the painting, I see that the "Start" Button is "bleeding" on to the `JPanel` where I'm painting the random lines.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Here's an executable Java code for recreating the issue. I'm also adding screenshots for more clarity.

---

```
package application;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RandomLines extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3312914356515718206L;

    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean init = false;

    private Point startPoint = getRandomPoint();
    private Point endPoint = getRandomPoint();

    public RandomLines() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(init == false) { 
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.black);

            init = true;
        }
        g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            repaint();
            delay();
            startPoint = endPoint;
            endPoint = getRandomPoint();
        }
    }

    private void delay() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private Point getRandomPoint() {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        int randX = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 % w);
        int randY = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 % h);

        return new Point(randX, randY);
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Random Lines");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton b = new JButton("Start");
        b.addActionListener(al -> {
            if (running == false) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
                running = true;
                b.setText("Stop");
                Thread t = new Thread(RandomLines.this);
                t.start();
            } else {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                running = false;
                b.setText("Start");
            }
        });
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, b, "Control Random Lines", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new String[]{"Close"}, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomLines rl = new RandomLines();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rl.createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

Here is a screen shot explaining the "bleeding" problem..

[image: Here is a screen shot explaining the "bleeding" problem..]

I hope I've detailed the question enough for others to understand. Let me know if you need more details.

> **Update**

One observation I had was that when I use multiple monitors and have the JOptionPane and JFrame on two different monitors. The problem does not occur.

But why does it even happen in the first place?

---

Comment: You broke the paint chain and failed to call `super.paintComponent`

Comment: And I have to admit: I find that design rather strange. Why do you do **everything** using `invokeLater()`. I would rather create/init your frame using the "main thread"; and then have a *scheduled* job make the required calls to update the UI via `invokeLater()` ... as said: your solution looks really strange too me; not like a really good practice. For example I am wondering if your call to invokeLater() will return at all ?!

Comment: I'd also suggest you have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a better solution, which won't need you to worry about synchonrising and multiple thread related issues and Swing thread safety

Comment: I added the call to `super.paintComponent(g);` Now, the "bleeding" problem went away. But it is also clearing out the lines that had been created in the previous iterations of `repaint();`

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Okay, I read through your comments on the other question's Answer. So I will need to repaint all those lines all over again!

Comment: @anacron Yes, that's how painting works, it's destructive. Alternatively, you could paint the lines to a `BufferedImage` and simply paint that each time `paintComponent` is called, there are pros and cons to both approaches

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you. I'll try out the `BufferedImage` option. Let's see how it works out for me. Thanks again!